# re.findall() can't find lines from a file in another file

Tags: python, regex, find

I have two text files: one with text from an article, and the other with a list of [phrasal verbs](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/phrasal-verb). I am trying to find each instance of each phrasal verb in the article. I know that the article contains the phrasal verb "log on", and so does the phrasal verb list. When I loop through the phrasal verbs and search for each one using re.findall(), it does not find any. When I manually start the loop at line 1199 of the phrasal verb list, which happens to be the word "log on", it finds it. When I start it just one line earlier, at line 1198, it does not find it. Here's my code:

```
import re
PV_HI = []
file = open('article.txt')
for line in open('phrasalVerbs.txt'):
    pv = line.strip()
    pvFound = re.findall(pv, file.read(), flags=re.I)
    PV_HI.extend(pvFound)
print(PV_HI)
```

Here's a sample of the phrasal verbs list text file:

```
Lock onto
Lock out
Lock up
Lock away
Log in
Log into
Log off
Log on
Log out
Look after
Look back
Look down on
Look for
Look forward to
Look in
Look in on
Look into
```

And a sample of the article file:

```
<p> If you have a business account, a higher Pay Anyone limit up to $500,000 and also have a Security Device to authorise third party payments and/or can add Operators, you are an ANZ Internet Banking for Business customer.
<p> How do I manage my accounts once I am registered for ANZ Internet Banking?
<p> If you have registered for ANZ Internet Banking, use your CRN and password to log on to ANZ Internet Banking.
<p> If you need help while logged on to ANZ Internet Banking, click the " Help " icon in the top right hand corner of all pages.
```

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is get a count of all phrasal verbs in a set of 1600 files. If there's a better way to do this, I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Thank you!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I save your sample of the phrasal verbs and the article file (append 'Log on' characters in the end to find), then use your python code to do some testing. In the beginning, I can't find any result too. But when I change the codes as below:

```
import re
PV_HI = []
with open('article.txt', 'r') as f:
    article_content = f.read()
    for line in open('phrasalVerbs.txt'):
        pv = line.strip()
        pvFound = re.findall(pv, article_content, flags=re.I)
        PV_HI.extend(pvFound)
    print(PV_HI)
```

It works and successfully finds 'Log on'. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome, thanks so much! I thought I would note that when I comment out `article_content = f.read()` and use `f.read()` as the string argument for `re.findall()`, it doesn't work, so assigning `f.read()` to a variable is crucial here. Thanks again!